# php: trying to call data from an object

Tags: php, arrays, object, call

I am trying to get specific data set from the object but unable to find out why I cannot call the number in my assignment.  This is it as follows:

```
$teir = $league->data->summonerLeagues->0->teir;
```

First of all this is calling the data from the league which is set and so that yo can see what the data looks like here it is:

```
stdClass Object
(
[data] => stdClass Object
    (
        [summonerLeagues] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [queue] => RANKED_SOLO_5x5
                        [name] => Dr. Mundo's Crushers
                        [tier] => BRONZE
                        [requestorsRank] => III
                        [entries] => Array
```

at this point I am trying to assign the variable $teir to teir in the object but they use 0 in the object and the way I am calling it must be the issue.....

Any suggestions?

Comment: FTR, you have `teir` misspelled in your call.

Answer (score 3):

Array access is with brackets, while object properties are accessed with `->`:

```
$tier = $league->data->summonerLeagues[0]->tier; // Fixed typo per @MikePurcell's comment
```